# Value: "" must be an instance of <class 'dict'> -> in django admin panel(using djongo to connect mongo database)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, djongo

I am using **Django** and connecting with a mongodb database using **djongo**. My database requirements are such that I need to use an [embedded field](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/) in one of the collections. On adding any entry on **Django Admin** I am getting a preview error -

I have 2 models, ***City*** containing 3 fields, and the ***Address*** containing 2 fields a city object and a pincode. Hence the city is an embedded field in model Address.

On adding the below entry through **django-admin** an error message pops up, and the entry doesn't get saved in the database.

[image]
As you can see above in the screenshot, the error message which gets displayed on saving this entry on django-admin is->
*Please correct the error below -> Value: gwalior-MP-India must be an instance of <class 'dict'>*

This is what is getting displayed on my IDE as soon as I click save entry in django-admin -
*[14/Oct/2022 10:17:45] "POST /admin/djangoApp/address/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7554

[14/Oct/2022 10:17:46] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3343*

*Here are the code snippets and the versions of the installed packages.*

***models.py***

```
class City(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    city = models.CharField(db_column='city', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(db_column='state', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(db_column='country', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city + '-' + self.state + '-' + self.country

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CityDetails'


class Address(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    # city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='city', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=City, null=True, blank=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(db_column='pincode', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Address'
```

***admin.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
    
class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['city', 'state', 'country']


class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['city', 'pincode']

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(City, CityAdmin)
admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
```

In ***settings.py***, the database settings part is-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'newDjangoDashboardProjectDb',
    }
}
```

My **requirements.txt** file-

```
>> tzdata==2022.5   
>> pytz==2022.4  
>> Django==4.1.2  
>> pymongo==3.12.3  
>> djongo==1.3.6  
>> wheel==0.37.1  
>> sqlparse==0.2.4  
>> mongodb==4.2.21
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas I am getting the error on django-admin panel, it just pops up when I try to save an entry in the django-form. I am not getting any error on the editor(PyCharm).



**This is what is getting displayed on my IDE -**
_[14/Oct/2022 10:17:45] "POST /admin/djangoApp/address/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7554   
[14/Oct/2022 10:17:46] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3343_